# "The requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system."

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, ini

Greetings fellow developers,

I am trying to use composer for a PHP project of mine on a development server I recently booted up and for some reason I am unable to. I successfully installed composer, however, when I try to run the *require* command I get the following error:

```
root@webserver:/var/mypersonal/index# composer require php-amqplib/php-amqplib
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^2.6 for php-amqplib/php-amqplib
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.3 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.6.0 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for php-amqplib/php-amqplib ^2.6 -> satisfiable by php-amqplib/php-amqplib[v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with the PHP warning I recieve right when running the *composer require* command but no google search results lead me to the correct direction.

Additionally, I have provided my */etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini* file incase of an error in that file.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc5bac59d684cbf575cef931ef36daf6 ***(I couldn't include the file in this post due to the character limit on posts.)***

Answer (score 102):

You can use function [get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) to see if `bcmath` modul is loaded. Or in terminal `php -m` or `php -m | grep name_of_the_modul`

You can install it depending on what OS you are using:

Ubuntu

`sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath`

CentOS

`yum install bcmath`

Comment: Just a note on installing it, if you run php -v you can check which version of PHP you're running. Mine was PHP 7.1.8-1ubuntu1. As I'm using 7.1, it had to install php7.1-bcmath instead.

Answer (score 29):

### PHP 7.2

#### Debian - jessie

> ```
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install php7.2-bcmath
> ```

work like a charm :)

Comment: working for me, we just need to change the version of php and package name in command line code as per the requirement. Ex. sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Docker:

- **bcmath** can be installed by running this command inside a container: `docker-php-ext-install bcmath`

Answer (score 15):

In Ubuntu 20.04

For php 7.4.3, `sudo apt install php7.4-bcmath`

Answer (score 14):

For any version in php Centos use

This solution worked for me

**yum install php-bcmath**

PHP will take the default version installed in the machine, search for that package and install it.

Delete the file composer.lock file if that is already created and then run again,

**composer install**

If you run

**composer update**

it will update whatever default packages are installed in composer.json which might create problem for you.

Answer (score 12):

For PHP 7.1, the following worked for me:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

Answer (score 9):

check your php version by type: `php --version`

you will see something like this:

```
PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1 ....
```

then `sudo apt install phpX.X-bcmath`  where X.X is php version, so for this ^ example it will be  `sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath`

after this check if module existed or not by type `php -m | grep bcmath`

Answer (score 8):

php 7.2 if you have other version just change it accordingly

For `CentOS`

```
sudo yum install php72-bcmath
```

For `Ubuntu`

```
sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath
```

Comment: for php 7.2  `sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath`

Comment: for php 7.4   sudo apt install php7.4-bcmath

Answer (score 6):

Run this command, hope it will works

```
sudo apt-get install php-bcmath
```

Answer (score 5):

hope this will fix the problem.

> ***sudo apt install php-bcmath***

Answer (score 3):

For this problem we should use **sudo apt install php-bcmath**

Comment: Are you sure about that? Even if that has been mentioned multiple times, you should add an explanation to that

Comment: Package 'php-bcmath' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2):

**Strange thing here**
Some month ago I have installed all PHP version in the same manner. In here are the 4 identically configured version of php: 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, with the same extensions (  when this was made possible ).
The strange thing was that ***bcmath*** is present for all php version excluding 7.1.
In the solution search I arrive here in this question, where the logic's things was confirmed installing bcmath, but in my Linode Debian 9 server the command
    ***apt install php7.1-bcmath***
doesn't work, with 3 error messages;

- E: Impossible to find the package php7.1-bcmath
- E: Impossible to find some package with glob "php7.1-bcmath"
- E: Impossible to find a package with the regular expression "php7.1-bcmath"

The goals no meet with any combination of tips and trick, refreshing apt cache, change Debian's mirrored server, installing yum, so on...

After some tentatives I had an illumination: modificating of ***/etc/apt/sources.list*** enabling the default Linode repository, then after an ***apt update*** (with no solution in the immediate), I have restored the /etc/apt/sources.list commenting out the Linode mirror sources again. Magically, after the new apt update the command now are working.

By this I confirm: ***apt install php7.1-bcmath*** is the right command, but your Debian can need a kick in the ass

Comment: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-bcmath'

Answer (score 2):

***Note: This will work on Ubuntu servers.***

**Start by navigating to the server's root directory:**

> /

**Install a particular PHP version, for example, PHP 7.4, by specifying it in the package name:**

> sudo apt-get install php7.4-bcmath

**After successfully installing the package, restart your Apache web server to activate the changes:**

> sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

Install with this command, thats work for me

```
apt-get install php-bcmath
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below package and it worked in Php version 5.6

```
yum install php56w-bcmath
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have already tried installing bc-math and still composer is giving errors.

Try this command

```
rm composer.lock
```

It will definitely work