# Cannot install php7.2-bcmath on Debian

Tags: linux, debian

I do everything according to the instructions: [PHP | "The requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45049601/php-the-requested-php-extension-bcmath-is-missing-from-your-system)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.2-bcmath
```

I get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done E: **Unable to locate package php7.2-bcmath** E:
> Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-bcmath'

Why the system cannot find this module?

Comment: Available is https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=bcmath

Answer (score 1):

Use [deb.sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/)
Just add https://packages.sury.org/php/ to Your apt/sources.list, and voila. There is  php7.2-bcmath and a lot of other php stuff

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me.
I added the code to the file (8th line)

```
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/
```

and it shows the error:

> E: Malformed line 8 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist) E: The
> list of sources could not be read.

So I added at the end last line: "jessie main"

```
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main
```

Now I have the same as before:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done E: Unable to locate package php7.2-bcmath E:
> Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-bcmath'

Why am I still unable to install this package?