# php7.2-bcmath (Debian Jessie) - installation problem

Tags: linux, debian, debian-jessie

When i try insstall this package i get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done E: Unable to locate package php7.2-bcmath E:
> Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-bcmath'

In source.list i have:

> deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main

Why is this package invisible on the system and cannot be installed?

Comment: You are using the public repository of a private person to install your software. Either use official sources or contact the owner of the repository at sury.org for missing packages.

Comment: Also make sure you are on correct versions, `php7.1-bcmath` doesn't match `php7.2-bcmath`.

Comment: Error in description, version php7.2 - I corrected the description

Comment: Here is information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895214/cannot-install-php7-2-bcmath-on-debian/67979233#67979233 Use deb.sury.org Just add https://packages.sury.org/php/ to Your apt/sources.list, and voila. There is php7.2-bcmath and a lot of other php stuff - but this dont work :/

Comment: There is `php7.2-bcmath` but there isn't `php7.2-bcmath` - I don't understand that. It is possible the vendor simply forgot to add that package to his repository, you need to contact that person. You did `apt-get update` right?

Comment: Of course I used apt-get update :)

Comment: Although you didn't mention, I'd suggest `docker pull php:7.2-stretch`. You could also replicate what they do to install from their [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2-zts-stretch/images/sha256-4c9c2ccb509be5e9afbc9347894e84d4e241c87752fcf174996f8ced38e538ed?context=explore).

Comment: docker pull php: 7.2-stretch - should I run it in the console? I get: docker: command not found...

Comment: You'd need to install Docker to use containers.

Answer (score 1):

jessie codename isn't supported in Sury repository. To list the permitted debian codenames:

```
curl -sSL https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/ | awk -F '"|/"' 'FNR >4 {print $2}'
```

sample output:

```
bullseye
buster
stretch
```

[Debian Jessie LTS reached End-Of-Life](https://www.patreon.com/posts/debian-jessie-of-39058626)

> the repositories have been removed with the last PHP update, so they are already gone.

To install `php7.2` you need to use the Freexian repository. See [PHP LTS by Freexian](https://php.freexian.com/) and [How to access the APT repositories](https://php.freexian.com/docs/access-apt-repositories/)

Comment: Freexian is paid. Is there really no way to install this stupid addon manually ??? It is very strange that installing a simple plugin can be such a problem...