# Keep getting errors with gcloud deployment of wordpress

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php, gcloud

Update: when I changed the user/pass for the database I got an error message on the url. (Telling me it was the wrong one) so changed it back again. It redirects to the wp-admin/install.php as it should on first time setup but screen stays white until “too many redirects” error shows up.

Can it be an sql database/privileges issue?

——

Since my current webhost is sold to one.com I expect a significant change in its resources and looking into options for hosting my pages.

One of the options I consider is Google Cloud, and have been trying to follow this guide from Google to setup a WP installation on App Engine (flexible)
https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible

I have followed it fairly point to point, but still I get an error that ends the deployment. And a build log I do not quite understand.

Anyone able to help me see what I might do differently?

Thanks.

Attaching the last lines of the build log if that may be helpful.

```
Step #2 - "build": === PHP - Composer Install (google.php.composer-install@0.0.1) ===
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: ***** CACHE MISS: "composer"
Step #2 - "build": 2023/08/26 20:29:35 [DEBUG] GET https://getcomposer.org/installer
Step #2 - "build": 2023/08/26 20:29:35 [DEBUG] GET https://composer.github.io/installer.sig
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "bash -c php -d 'error_reporting=24575' -r \"echo hash_file('sha384', '/layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/composer-setup-3864911110.php');\""
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bcmath.so' (tried: /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Step #2 - "build": e21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02Done "bash -c php -d 'error_reporting=24575' -r \"echo hash_file('s..." (394.388766ms)
Step #2 - "build": Failure: (ID: c10ac683) Failed to run /bin/build: invalid composer installer found at "https://getcomposer.org/installer": checksum for composer installer, "Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bcmath.so' (tried: /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/bcmath.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0\n\nWarning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0\ne21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02", does not match expected checksum of "e21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02"
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-2936771480149100651 /builder/outputs/output"
Step #2 - "build": Done "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-2936771480149100651 /builder/o..." (14.840729ms)
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/php/builder:php_20230807_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 51
```

Comment: have bcmath installed already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45049601/the-requested-php-extension-bcmath-is-missing-from-your-system

Comment: Anything unclear about the error message? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to install the extentions locally before deploying, adding them to composer as required, removing them from php.ini.
Keep everything updated to the latest versions.

Comment: What do you mean by "locally before deploying"? They need to be installed on the server where your application runs, not on any other system. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase This is on a google cloud (app engine) 
An my question is how to install it there, through gcloud cli. 

Since in seems to fail. Though I´ve used Googles own instructions and guides, and sample files.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What have you tried to install that extension? How is that related to Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can't find a way to install the extenstions to Google Cloud (app engine)

Comment: bcmath is installed and enabled in App Engine Flexible [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#using_extensions). Something else is wrong, but your post only shows error message without configuration files, etc. If you are using an older version of PHP, try the latest supported version.

Comment: @JohnHanley using php 8.2.9.